# Automatically login to an ssh-agent session in a non-user shell

Tags: shell, ssh-agent

My team shares a user account via a non-user shell on a few systems for reasons beyond our control. We all move our passphrase protected private keys to the share'd users ~/.ssh directory. We normally login and open an `ssh-agent` session then `ssh-add` our passphrase protected keys like below. None of us like this workflow and we're trying to make it easier.

Is there a way we can automatically be prompted for our passphrase when we open the shared user's shell?

```
sudo -u shared /bin/bash
# new shell opens
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_username_rsa
# enter passphrase and continue...
```

Answer (score 0):

So the key to be added should depend on the user who started the sudo session? the `SUDO_USER` environment variable might be what you need?

Put something like the following in the `shared` user's shell startup file
(say `.bash_login` for Bash. Though you'll need to start the shell as a  login shell with `sudo -i`):

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/${SUDO_USER}_rsa
```

or even

```
if [ "$SUDO_USER" = userthis ] ; then 
    echo do something for this user
elif...
fi
```

Of course downside of such a shared account is that all of you will effectively own each other's keys, since the keys are saved under a single user id and there's nothing to separate different users of the shared account.

I'm not sure if it would be possible to start an `ssh-agent` before the `sudo` under your normal account, and then use it from the sudoed shell. I suppose it would at least require fixing the permissions of the agent's socket, and even then, other users of the same account could use the keys in the agent, though perhaps not copy them.

Answer (score 0):

I would, as you:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh -A shared@localhost
```

Then you don't have to put your private key files in a directory in the shared user.